# Creating a promise without the new keyword

Tags: javascript, promise

After watching [fun fun function](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3zzCY62NYc&t=1s), I decided not to use the `new` keyword.

But here is a foundational example of how to use promises:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Stuff worked!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("It broke"));
  }
});
```

Q: How do I create a promise without the use of the `new` keyword?

Comment: Why have you decided not to use the `new` keyword? Did you watch and understand the video? You can follow the example in the video exactly... not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Promise is an object. If it so, it should be used with `new` for creation new examples of this object...

Comment: Don't trust every video you watch on YouTube.

Comment: @Sergey, `new` does not create new examples of the `Promise` object. `Promise` is a constructor (a function). You create *examples* of `Promise.prototype`, not `Promise`.

Comment: Seems like a pretty pointless objective to avoid the supported and well understood and simple way of creating a promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a pure academic question, you *could* work around `new` by creating a thenable (for which you don't need `new`), and then you can convert that thenable to a full-blown promise with `Promise.resolve`:

```js
function createPromise(executor) {
    let callback;
    function resolve(resolution, arg) {
        Promise.resolve().then(function () {
            callback[resolution](arg);
        });
    }
    try {
        executor(resolve.bind(null, "fulfill"), resolve.bind(null, "reject"));
    } catch(e) {
        resolve("reject", e);
    }
    return Promise.resolve({ 
        then: function (fulfill, reject) {
            callback = { fulfill, reject };
        }
    });
}

// Demo
var prom1 = createPromise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () { resolve("Stuff worked!") }, 1000);
});
var prom2 = createPromise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () { reject("It broke") }, 1000);
});

prom1.then(function (v) { console.log(v); });
prom2.catch(function (err) { console.log(err) });
console.log('waiting for promises to resolve');
```

Some have reasons to avoid the use of `new`, but if that has to lead to the above code, then clearly some exceptions should be allowed. Unless someone has a better idea to create promises without the use of `new`, one has to implement some Promise characteristics *again* (such as the `try ... catch` and the *asynchronous* call of the `then` callback) only to work around `new`. This seems a bad idea.

Conclusion: just use `new` for creating new promises.

Comment: Why is this so complicated?  Why not just make a factory function: `function createPromise(executor) {return new Promise(executor);}`

Comment: Because the question was to do it without `new`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `async/await`

```
const getPromise = async () => {
    // do a thing, possibly async, then…

    if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
        return 'Stuff worked!'
    } else {
        throw 'It broke'
    }
});
const promise = getPromise()
```

But please realize that you can't just call `Error`, calling constructor without `new` keyword throws garbage to `global` object in NodeJS (or to `window` object in browser JS). You have to use `new Error`. I hope I didn't create a whole new problem for you.

Also, note that `async/await` is just a syntactic sugar, the code will run with `new` anyway. Also, I suggest not to take advice literally. Granted, `new` is evil, but sometimes necessary in order not to over-complicate things.

Comment: of course, and this is meant as a serious answer, what is the problem ?

Comment: No more problem ;-)

Comment: Actually he recommends against using async await as well. https://youtu.be/-Yv2qljLrns?t=4m9s

Comment: hnnnng, yeah, that happened, slightly humiliating. Thanks for poking me.

Comment: oh wait you meant the 'dude' remark. True, sorry about that. But I just fixed a terrible mistake in the code as well :)

Comment: You don't have to use `new` to create a new error, `Error(...)` can act as a factory function as well ([ref](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-error-constructor)).

Comment: How is this solution going to resolve a promise *asynhcronously*? You'll need to `await` something... but what? A promise? How will you create it? With `new`?

Comment: The original question does not consider resolving the promise, only creating it and that's what the `async` function does (no need to use `await`).

Comment: If that were the question then `Promise.resolve()` is the answer. But from the OP's code example it is clear they need support for asynchronously fulfilling and rejecting promises.

Answer (score 1):

MDN's [Promise.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [Promise.reject()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)
man pages show how those functions return `then`ables.

The following code snippet goes a step further to show how they can be used to make `myFunc` wrap `_myFunc` to return a `then`able.

```js
'strict';

function _myFunc(tf){
  if (tf)
    return; 
  throw new Error('flubbed it');
}
function myFunc(tf){
  try { return Promise.resolve(_myFunc(tf));}
  catch(e) { return Promise.reject(e);}
}

function main() {
  try {
    _myFunc(false);
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`FAILED: ${e.message}`);
  }

  try {
    _myFunc(true);
    console.log('SUCCESS');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`FAILED: ${e.message}`);
  }

  myFunc(false)
    .then(()=>{ console.log('success'); })
    .catch((e)=>{ console.log(`failed: ${e.message}`); });

  myFunc(true)
    .then(()=>{ console.log('success'); })
    .catch((e)=>{ console.log(`failed: ${e.message}`); });

}

main();
```

However, because there are no promises, there is no `await` either, and we are back to the [pyramid of doom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) when it comes to synchronizing.
As you can see in the output

```
FAILED: flubbed it
SUCCESS
success
failed: flubbed it
```

the order of last two results are out of order.  That is because the JS interpreter sees the use of a `then`able as an instruction to run the command asynchronously.

In conclusion, the great thing about `Promise`s is the ability to `await` and use `Promise.all` or `Promise.race` etc, which require `Promise`s with state, for which `new Promise(...)` is obviously required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper function:

```
const Guarantee = function () {
  var _resolve = null
  var _reject = null

  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    _resolve = resolve
    _reject = reject
  })

  promise.resolve = function () {
    _resolve.apply(promise, arguments)
  }

  promise.reject = function () {
    _resolve.apply(promise, arguments)
  }

  return promise
}

function doSomething () {
  const promise = Guarantee()

  setTimeout(function () {
    promise.resolve('123')
  }, 1000)

  return promise
}

doSomething()
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

- https://github.com/webarthur/node-guarantee
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-guarantee

Enjoy!